# Is it true that $ \left\{{\inf\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}}{h_n} \leq c \right\} = \bigcup_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{ h_n \leq c \right\} $?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $h_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions. I managed to prove the following equalities (measurability is not relevant in this case):

$$\left\{{\inf_{n \in \mathbb N}}{h_n} \geq c \right\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{  h_n  \geq c \right\},$$

$$\left\{{\sup_{n \in \mathbb N}}{h_n} \leq c \right\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{  h_n  \leq c \right\}$$

and therefore the equalities of the respective complements:

$$\left\{{\inf_{n \in \mathbb N}}{h_n} < c \right\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{  h_n  < c \right\},$$

$$\left\{{\sup_{n \in \mathbb N}}{h_n} > c \right\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{  h_n  > c \right\}$$

However, I cannot prove that, for example,

$$\left\{{\inf_{n \in \mathbb N}}{h_n} > c \right\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{  h_n  > c \right\},$$
or $$\left\{{\inf_{n \in \mathbb N}}{h_n} \leq c \right\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{  h_n  \leq c \right\}  $$

The last equalities first came up in my tutorial class and I also found them on page 20 (8) of this pdf: http://www.applebaum.staff.shef.ac.uk/Ch2MeasFn.pdf. Can someone clarify whether these equalities hold and, if so, give a detailed demonstration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the constant functions $h_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and $c=0$. 
Then we have
\begin{align}
\left\{ \inf_{n} h_n \le 0 \right\} = \left\{ \inf_{n} \frac{1}{n} \le 0 \right\} = \Omega.
\end{align}
On the other hand we have
\begin{align}
\bigcup_{n} \left\{ h_n \le 0 \right\} = \bigcup_{n} \left\{ \frac{1}{n} \le 0 \right\} = \emptyset.
\end{align}
So the equalities  do not hold.